# Вращение камеры свайпом в 3D Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Мне нужно чтобы игрок пальцем перемещал камеру, камера постоянно летит прямо, если повернуть вправо, то камера повернется вправо на отрезок пройденный от начала свайпа до конца, если вверх то вверх. Мне не подходят OnPointerUp и OnPointerDown, потому-что нужно чтобы во время свайпа камера уже двигалась, я пробовал OnDrag, но не смотря на мои гениальные расчеты все работает не правильно,подскажите как расчитать правильно, или как ещё можно реализовать это

Comment: Как в этом видосе 
https://youtu.be/cRhsPhRewr4

Comment: `OnPointerUp`, `OnPointerDown` и `OnDrag` это интерфейсы для UI, всё равно что забивать гвозди отверткой. `Input`!

Comment: GetMouseButton подходит, но подскажите как сделать правильно изменение rotation, у меня срака какая-то получается, почему-то z изменяется хотя я его не трогаю

Comment: Сраку в студию.